# Shortcut to python IDLE on mac os

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

I want to create a shortcut for IDLE on my mac so that I don't need to go through the terminal. Is there a way to do this? I was trying Automator but I'm not that familiar with it.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to run python in terminal or in idle stand alone app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `shell script` to do what you need on `osx`.

Instructions to open a `python` interpreter in terminal:

- First create a file called `python.command`
- Open the file in any text editor and copy and paste the following

  `#!/bin/bash`

  `python`
- If you want to open the `IDLE Standalone App` do the following (repeat step 1,2 but paste the following) but make sure your path is correct:

  `#!/bin/bash`

  `open -a /Applications/Python\ 2.7/IDLE.app`

Comment: That's cool but is there a way to open IDLE without touching the terminal?

Comment: You dont touch the terminal, all you do is double click the file, `python.command`

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'm going to accept this as my answer but in the interest of OCD, can this be put onto the menu bar somehow?

Comment: @Matt Yes it can. Drag the file to the right of the navigation divisor line on the dock

Answer (score -1):

You can use spotlight to open IDLE: Press CMD (Apple) + SPACE, type "idle" and hit ENTER...
my preferred way to open any programs on the mac

Comment: IDLE doesn't show up on spotlight. That was (and is) my go to as well, but I can't do it in this instance.

Comment: I see, you excluded it somehow then. Another way: you could create a Desktop-Shortcut to the IDLE app. Just search for IDLE.app in your Programs folder and create an alias on it. You can drag this alias to your desktop.